# Static content in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I've got a website and I'd like to make a part of it static. What happens is that the header, the menu bar and the footer are consistent in every page. I'd like to have them always loaded and when I click the menu button, it will only reload what is the body of the site.

Is there a simple chunck of code that can early achieve this? Something in js or ajax? I'm sorry but I don't have enough experience in these languages to accomplish something on my own. I've already tried to check jQuery library but it's still pretty confusing to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at EDIT2 of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466818/static-content-in-website/11467136#11467136

Answer (score 1):

Just add in every page a div container with ID for header, menubar and footer and just load it with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#header').load('header.html');
    $('#menubar').load('menubar.html');
    $('#footer').load('footer.html');
});
```

Just make sure that the html files don't have html, head or body tags within, only the HTML-Code you would write inside the div. It's just like the include function in PHP.

**EDIT:**

For easy and simple implementation store the code above inside a .js file (e.g. include.js) and add this inside every head just below the include of all other scripts of your html files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include.js"></script>
```

**EDIT2:**

Another solution ist to load the content of the page instead of the header, menubar, footer.
Here you take the same specifications (no html, body, etc. tags inside your content html files)

Name your content div e.g. `<div id="content"></div>`

Your navbar for example:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="content1.html">Content1</a>
    <a href="content2.html">Content2</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Click on a link that's child of the navbar
    $('#navbar > a').click(function() {
        //Get the html file (e.g. content1.html)
        var file = $(this).attr('href');
        //Load this file into the #content
        $('#content').load(file);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution too. I'm using the morning to work on something else but right after lunch I'll pick up where I left on the website and try the various ways that everyone left here. Your's seems clean and fast.

Comment: With this the user can take a look at the content, even when javascript is disabled, cause it's a normal link to the page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't even need Ajax or css!! Just use iFrames!! They are awesome, what happens is that u only design one page as the holder of your static content (Header-Menu ...) and put one iFrame in there as a place holder for any page you want to load in it, u should use proper css code to place the iFrame where you want, now, for every link in your menu, just set the "target" attribute equal to your iFrame's name and all the links will be loaded in that iFrame and your page won't be reloaded with every link click... I'll be back with some code...

Comment: No they are NOT AWESOME - They are completely deprecated

Comment: Yes, Yes, they are old, but they make this job really easy... I mean, REALLY easy!!!

Comment: Now we have jQuery I do not agree

Comment: jQuery means Javascript, and so accessibility is not reached ... but any way, Frames are definitly not the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the use of Server Side Included : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

It's not quite easy to understand (as it refer to apache configuration), but this is a really great solution.

In a nutshell, you include parts of html code in you main page :

```
 <!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->
```

You won't have to use or understand all JQuery Framewol, user agent won't have to parse (if they are able to !) Javascript.

This is a pretty good replacement of PHP / ASP / Java for this kind of purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ajax to request the body of each page. But this is only one possibility - there are many. An other approach could be to create you page content using a script language (php, perl) serverside and employ a function there which adds footer, header and anything else to each page.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an idea of Jquery then use click event on menu links to load the page in a div like the following syntax may help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.menu").click(function(){
      $("#bodyContent").load("http://abc.com/your-linked-page.html");
   });
});
```

To load the url dynamically use the following code:
In your menu bar the link looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Specify-Complete-URL">Home</a>
```

In your Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.menu").click(function(){
      url = $(this).attr("title"); // here url is just a variable
      $("#bodyContent").load(url);
   });
});
```

Step 1: Add Jquery file into your html page.

Step 2: Use the above jquery code and change your menu link to the new what i said here.

Step 3: If you done it correctly, It will work for you.

Comment: load method will automatically do the same thing if you are not very much familiar with the ajax. It may be a bit simpler way.

Comment: It exactly worked for me. Please ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to digest it and get something happening.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for your response.

Comment: What is the best way to implement your code? I'm a bit lost :).

Comment: Very poor practice to have javascript in the href and a URL in the title. Instead have the url in the href and the site will degrade gracefully. JQuery can still load the href and stop the click. If you MUST use a var, use the DATA attribute instead of title which is used by screen readers

Comment: I wrote this code on the fly and gave him the way to complete his task. However there is always a possibility to improve the code. By the way, Thanks mplungjan. I will try to write the efficient code from my next answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about a traditional `iframe`?

In your menu:

```
<a target="body" href="URL_to_your_Menu1_page">Menu1</a>
```

and then further in the document:

```
<iframe name="body" src="URL_to_homepage"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

You may use frameset and frames and organize you pages accordingly. So, frames containing menus can always be at display and while displaying contents on click of menu u may set target to frame in which you would like to load the contents.

Comment: There is no HTML5 support for `frameset`s.

Comment: So there is no change to use HTML itself? It would be good not to dive into JavaScript or Ajax. The problem is that I don't know how to write the code myself. Are there any already made scripts to accomplish this?

Comment: Frame sets and frames is so last millennium!